# Rendering multiple scenes in blender render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Basiclly I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBRMh5QZ1n8

and I've done everything correctly but when I render it, only the text renders without the extra halo scenes. here are some screen-shots if it helps:[image] (I think)

If you need more screenshots or info just say specifically as i'm kinda new to blender only started properly learning it like 5 days ago.

EDIT: Ye that helped with the transparency but no luck the text is on it's own still when rendered [image]

If anyone would be kind enough to go through the file and see what's wrong here is the link ;) [image]

or request more screenshots if you need more info.

Comment: Upload your file to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) instead. Edit your question and include the link given to you once the upload is complete.

Comment: I believe I found you problem. Did you set the Alpha to Transparent on **all** scenes? If so, change it back to Sky on Scene.001 and Scene.002.

Comment: You have to selected "Composite" instead of "Renderlayer" in the image editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scene with the text doesn't look liike it has any transparency, so when you Alpha Over it on another image, it completely covers that image. Change *Alpha* to *Transparent* under *Shading* in the Render tab. Change this **only** on the scene named Scene in your file. Scene.001 and Scene.002, which contain the halos, should keep the default setting, *Sky*. The halos really do get rendered, but they are so faint, that they're just not visible enough without a background.

[image]

You can also set them all to transparent and insert a second *Alpha Over* node like this, to be able to contro, the background colour.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, the transparency was the problem and how faint the halo's were. Thanks for everyone's contribution :D couldn't find an answer to this anywhere.

Comment: @Encryptor You're welcome. I had a similar problem once, and it took me some time to solve it.

Comment: sorry but with my luck obviously this is just the beginning the text is treating the scenes as background and I want them to render together, so that the halo's in front of the text like smoke and red glowing dots appear in front of it as well, first I thought; oh the halos are further than the camera so no particle is actually in front of the text but then i made it really dense and it still treats it as a background. :P any help with my never ending problem?

Comment: - ignore me I'm just being an idiot XD